# Problem mapping LDAP configurations to Rundeck’s JAAS parameters

Tags: ldap, jaas, rundeck

I am trying to integrate LDAP authentication to [rundeck](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/security/authentication.html#ldap).

I can query the users using `ldapsearch` successfully like below

```
ldapsearch -v -x -D "some_address@myorg.lan" -b "dc=myorg,dc=lan" -H ldap://ldaphost.myorg.lan -w **** "uid=user_1"
```

which returns:

```
ldap_initialize( ldap://ldaphost.myorg.lan:389/??base )
filter: uid=user_1
requesting: All userApplication attributes
# extended LDIF
#
# LDAPv3
# base <dc=myorg,dc=lan> with scope subtree
# filter: uid=user_1
# requesting: ALL
#

# user_1@myorg.lan, Users, myorg, Zones, Circular, warehouse, myorg
 .lan
dn: CN=user_1@myorg.lan,CN=Users,CN=myorg,CN=Zones,OU=Circular,OU=warehouse,DC=myorg,DC=lan
objectClass: top
objectClass: posixAccount
objectClass: leaf
objectClass: connectionPoint
objectClass: serviceConnectionPoint
cn: user_1@myorg.lan
distinguishedName: CN=user_1@myorg.lan,CN=Users,CN=myorg,CN=Zones,OU=Circular,OU=warehouse,DC=myorg,DC=lan
instanceType: 4
whenCreated: 20190128081317.0Z
whenChanged: 20200128081329.0Z
displayName: $CimsUserVersion5
uSNCreated: 221081209
uSNChanged: 221081209
showInAdvancedViewOnly: TRUE
name: user_1@myorg.lan
objectGUID:: XG234o3+m0iVYGHHJKODVQ==
keywords: parentLink:S-1-5-21-******-*****-*****-1***3
objectCategory: CN=Service-Connection-Point,CN=Schema,CN=Configuration,DC=myorg,DC=lan
dSCorePropagationData: 20210805091319.0Z
dSCorePropagationData: 20210805084748.0Z
dSCorePropagationData: 20210921114113.0Z
dSCorePropagationData: 20210405111238.0Z
dSCorePropagationData: 16020914223649.0Z
uid: user_1
unixHomeDirectory: %{home}/%{user}
uidNumber: 763534041
gecos: %{u:displayName}
loginShell: /bin/bash
gidNumber: 20003

# search reference
ref: ldap://myorg.lan/CN=Configuration,DC=myorg,DC=lan

# search reference
ref: ldap://ForestDnsZones.myorg.lan/DC=ForestDnsZones,DC=myorg,DC=lan

# search reference
ref: ldap://DomainDnsZones.myorg.lan/DC=DomainDnsZones,DC=myorg,DC=lan

# search result
search: 2
result: 0 Success

# numResponses: 5
# numEntries: 1
# numReferences: 3
```

However, now I am confused which information maps to which parameter in Rundeck's [JettyCachingLdapLoginModule](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/security/authentication.html#ldap). e.g. whether `distinguishedName: CN=user_1@myorg.lan,CN=Users,CN=myorg,CN=Zones,OU=Circular,OU=warehouse,DC=myorg,DC=lan` is a `bindDn`, `userBaseDn` or `roleBaseDn`?

I don't have direct access to the LDAP server, so only way to retrieve information is through `ldapsearch`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the user name to access the LDAP `binDn`.

[Here](https://docs.rundeck.com/docs/administration/security/authentication.html#login-module-configuration) you can see all attributes explained.

`bindDn`: is optional. If not using "binding" authentication, set this to the root DN that should bind, e.g. "cn=Manager,dc=example,dc=com".

`userBaseDn`: is the base DN to search for users, example: "ou=People,dc=test1,dc=example,dc=com".

`roleBaseDN`: is the Base DN for role membership search, e.g. "ou=Groups,dc=test1,dc=example,dc=com".

Another great tool to check your LDAP server is [Apache Directory Studio](https://directory.apache.org/studio/).