# Rundeck LDAP configuration problems

Tags: ldap, rundeck

I am trying to configure rundeck with an new ldap - the old one was working fine.
I always get

> LDAP: error code 49 - Invalid Credentials

I tried already several things.
I verified the certificates and credentials by commandline tool ldapsearch.

I added all necessary certificates to /etc/rundeck/ssl/truststore and also /home/rundeck/etc/rundeck/ssl/truststore
I also listed the certificates from the JAVA keystore, with

> keytool -list -keystore $JAVA_HOME/lib/security/cacerts -storepass changeit

I tried two different types of installations
With the war file and and a "jaas-ldap.conf" as it was working for the old ldap

```
ldap {
    com.dtolabs.rundeck.jetty.jaas.JettyCachingLdapLoginModule sufficient
        debug="true"
        contextFactory="com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory"
        providerUrl="ldaps://our.ldap.org:636"
        bindDN="uid=icrundeck,ou=accounts,ou=ims_service,o=ourorg,c=GB"
        bindPassword="xxxxxxxxx"
        authenticationMethod="simple"
        forceBindingLogin="true"
        userBaseDn="ou=users,ou=icrundeck,ou=ims_service,o=ourorg,c=GB"
        userRdnAttribute="uid"
        userIdAttribute="uid"
        userObjectClass="inetOrgPerson"
        roleBaseDn="ou=roles,ou=icrundeck,ou=ims_service,o=ourorg,c=GB"
        roleNameAttribute="cn"
        roleUsernameMemberAttribute="uid"
        roleMemberAttribute="member"
        roleObjectClass="posixGroup"
        supplementalRoles="Users"
        cacheDurationMillis="300000"
        reportStatistics="true";

    org.eclipse.jetty.jaas.spi.PropertyFileLoginModule required
        debug="true"
        file="/home/rundeck/server/config/realm.properties";
};
```

and the Rundeck Docker Container with environment docker variables:

```
environment:
      RUNDECK_LOGGING_STRATEGY: FILE
      RUNDECK_JAAS_MODULES_0: JettyCombinedLdapLoginModule
      RUNDECK_JAAS_LDAP_DEBUG: "true"
      RUNDECK_JAAS_LDAP_FLAG: sufficient
      RUNDECK_JAAS_LDAP_PROVIDERURL: ldaps://our.ldap.org:636
      RUNDECK_JAAS_LDAP_FORCEBINDINGLOGIN: false
      RUNDECK_JAAS_LDAP_BINDDN: uid=icrundeck,ou=accounts,ou=ims_service,o=ourorg,c=GB
      RUNDECK_JAAS_LDAP_BINDPASSWORD: xxxxxxxx
      RUNDECK_JAAS_LDAP_USERBASEDN: ou=users,ou=icrundeck,ou=ims_service,o=ourorg,c=GB
      RUNDECK_JAAS_LDAP_ROLEBASEDN: ou=roles,ou=icrundeck,ou=ims_service,o=ourorg,c=GB
      RUNDECK_JAAS_MODULES_1: PropertyFileLoginModule
      RUNDECK_JAAS_FILE_FLAG: sufficient
```

I don't know how to proceed here now and what I can test now.
And how can I enable DEBUG mode for JAAS_MODULE inside the Docker container.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Hi, try adding the cert to the java cacert and disable the truststore reference, take a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75403311/10426011

Answer (score 0):

I could enabling root level debug mode inside the container with this environment variable:

```
    environment:
      RUNDECK_LOGGING_LOGLEVEL_ROOT: "debug"
```

and this shows me two lines

```
[2023-03-22T15:33:54,661] DEBUG jaas.JettyCachingLdapLoginModule - Searching for users with filter: '(&(objectClass={0})({1}={2}))' from base dn: ou=users,ou=icrundeck,ou=ims_service,o=ourorg,c=GB
[2023-03-22T15:33:54,728] DEBUG jaas.JettyCachingLdapLoginModule - Found user?: false
```

Which means the search filter is somehow wrong

This looks also related to my problem
[Problem mapping LDAP configurations to Rundeck’s JAAS parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74200973/problem-mapping-ldap-configurations-to-rundeck-s-jaas-parameters)